# Fix the invalid syntax issue with numpy.linalg.norm()

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following error with numpy.linalg.norm()

```
m = np.array([[1,2,3,4]])
print numpy.linalg.norm(x)
```

I get the following error:

```
m = np.array([[1,2,3,4]])
print numpy.linalg.norm(x)
  File "<ipython-input-14-47fc20ca64fe>", line 2
    print numpy.linalg.norm(x)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Are you using Python 3? `print` is a function, not a keyword, in Python 3.

Comment: In Python 3, `print()` is a function.  Use `print(foo)`, not `print foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors: 1) you are passing x instead of m into the `norm()` function and 2) you are using `print()` syntax for Python 2 instead of Python 3. Python 3 prints are done as `print("STRING")` with the parenthesis.

```
foo = "hello"

# Python 2
print foo 

# Python 3
print(foo)
```

Your code fixed:

```
m = np.array([[1,2,3,4]])
print(np.linalg.norm(m))
```

The result is: `5.477225575051661`